# Crosswalk crashes with cordova-plugin-file when read file larger than 20MB

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I'm using cordova-plugin-file to read my mp3 file with the readAsArrayBuffer method. It works perfect with a file less than 20mb, but with a larger file it causes the app to crash with this error. (I'm using crosswalk browser)

`E/chromium( 3330): [ERROR:simple_index_file.cc(223)] Failed to write the temporary index file
 E/chromium( 3330): [ERROR:runtime_javascript_dialog_manager.cc(69)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::RuntimeJavaScriptDialogManager::ResetDialogState(content::WebContents*)`

I'm so confused with what the problem is. Does the problem come from xwalk or cordova-plugin-file?
 Please help me because this plugin can only read file smaller than 20mb size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this bug.
I think [Cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) can't send large amount of data from native to javascript. So I try to research from Crosswalk Browser API and very happy to see that they support [**File API**](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/tree/master/experimental/native_file_system). It can get access directly to Android file system through `virtual root` like : `EXTERNAL`, `CACHEDIR`, `DOWNLOADS`, ...
Here is the trick to read any big file with Crosswalk:

```
function readFileAsArrayBuffer(storage, path, file) {
    xwalk.experimental.native_file_system.requestNativeFileSystem(storage,
    function (fs) {
       fs.root.getFile(storage + "/" + path + file, {create: false}, function (entry) {
           entry.file(function (file) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (data) {
                   //Data after read.
                };
                  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                },
            },
            function (e) {
              console.error("2-" + JSON.stringify(e))
            });
        },
        function (e) {
          console.error("3-" + JSON.stringify(e));
        });
}
//test
readFileAsArrayBuffer("EXTERNAL", "downloads/folder/", "file.mp3");
```